# Why am I getting the following error message: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: ‘int’ and ‘str’. See below the python rules body

Tags: python

classlist : MgtT3GrpB_1920.csv

student_identifier : ID

group_size : 4+

- distribute : Degree 
  values : (food, eng, arts, law, sc, nurse)
- distribute : Group1 
  values : (i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, viii, ix, x)
- distribute : Group2 
  values : (cab, fox, monk, dun, Blrk, merr, ran, step, goat, leop)
- distribute : Group3 
  values : (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
- distribute : Group4 
  values : (DELL, Link, Google, SAP, Oracle, IBM, Workday, eBay, Airbnb)
- balance : Work Experience
- balance : Ethnicity
- balance : Gender
- balance : Qual_Quant

Comment: Please add the code that is giving you the error. This does not help much.

Comment: What you are trying to say?
Please elaborate

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I am using a pre-coded programme with groupeng-1.3. I just need to input my rules and direct it to the .csv file through their groupeng-1.3 python programme. I'm not sure if my terminology is correct. It works with their sample and csv file they have provided, but when I put in my own rules, it gives the operand error.

Comment: I have tried to open the groupeng-1.3 file through python to view the code, but it opens and closes in a split second, so I cannot view it.

Comment: Neither your post or your comments make sense. We have no idea what you're talking about, and what you're working with. You should delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

find out what are the types of variables which you are trying to use + on by using:
type(x) 
where x is your variable name. int(x) might solve the issue.
Also, this might happen if you 
1. have some characters in the column in the file where you expect only numbers, solution is to clean the file
2. you have null values which were not recognized during import of file. If you are using pandas read_csv you might need to set na_values parameter.